# How to get current route in canActive route?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing

I want to restrict route as per role. I want to check whether navigated route does have permission to access page or not in my canActivate method. But, `this.router.url` this giving me previous route instead of current navigated route.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot` can solve you problem:

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
      console.log(route.url);

      ...
}
```

You can [see full spec here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html) for the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` object:

Answer (score 9):

You might be interested in getting the url from the `RouterStateSnapshot` parameter in this version of the `canActivate` method to get the complete path (tested with Angular 5):

```
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
       console.log(state.url);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and `RouterStateSnapshot` to resolve your problem.

Here is code sample from my Angular2 application.

> auth-guard.ts

```
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthCookie } from '../shared/services/auth-cookies-handler';

@Injectable()
export default class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private _authCookie: AuthCookie) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        if (this._authCookie.getAuth()) {
            //add your custom conditions for route nevigation
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> app.routing.ts

```
import {ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home';
import {LoginComponent } from '../account/login';
import { RegisterComponent } from '../account/register';
import { JourneyComponent } from '../journey/journey.component';
import AuthGuard from './auth-guard';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }, {
        path: 'journey',
        component: JourneyComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'details', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'details', component: JourneyDetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: 'documents', component: DocumentsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: 'review', component: ReviewComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
            { path: 'payment', component: PaymentComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
        ]
        , canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'application',
        component: ApplicationComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'activate-account/:uid',
        component: AccountComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'reset-password/:uid',
        component: ResetPasswordComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Hope this will help You!